# If $$ has $()=(^\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, is it also true that a) $d(n) = o(n)$, and b) that $d(n)^2 = o(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, limits

This is a two part question. First, I'm trying to understand how important the power $\varepsilon$ in the little-o notation theorem concerning the divisor function is. It seems to me that the divisor function grows far more slowly than $(n)$ so it shouldn't be a surprise if $d(n) = o(n)$, with or without the powers. Am I misunderstanding something? So:

1. If $$ has $()=(^\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, is it also true that $d(n) = o(n)$ ?

(and hence that if $()/(^\varepsilon)$ -> 0, then $()/$ -> 0)

2. How much can you play around with $d(n)$ before it fails to be true that $d(n) = o(n)$? Specifically, is it true that 
   $d(n) = o(n)$ implies $(d(n))^2 = o(n)$?

(and similarly that if $()/()$ -> 0, then $()^2/$ -> 0)

Thank you!

Comment: $d(n)=o(n)$ does not imply $(d(n))^2=o(n)$, but $\forall\epsilon>0,d(n)=o(n^{\epsilon})$ does.

Comment: Thanks Gerry that’s great news in fact. Can you offer an explanation why in both cases?

Comment: It follows immediately from the definition of the little-oh notation. Do you know what $f(n)=o(g(n))$ means?

Comment: Partly I'm trying to understand it by asking these questions! Why does it follow directly? Thanks

Comment: Please, do you know what $f(n)=o(g(n))$ means?

Comment: Yes insofar as I know it means g(x) expands much faster than f(x), enough that f(x)/g(x) ->0. What I’m unsure of is why that implies that f(x)^2/g(x) -> 0.

Comment: As I wrote in my very first comment, $d(n)=o(n)$ does **not** imply $(d(n))^2=o(n)$.

Comment: Yes, typo. ... d(n)= o(n^e). Still be grateful for the explanation.

Comment: Since you know the definitions, write out the meaning of $\forall\epsilon>0,d(n)=o(n^{\epsilon})$ and the meaning of $(d(n))^2=o(n)$ and stare at them and I'm sure you'll be able to work out why the first implies the second.

Comment: Not helpful, Gerry.

Comment: OK. Please, write out, here, the meaning of $\forall\epsilon>0,d(n)=o(n^{\epsilon})$, and write out, here, the meaning of $(d(n))^2=o(n)$, and we'll look at them together. (but possibly tomorrow, as it's getting late here now)

Comment: Ha, ok I figured it out. It implies that d(n)=o(n^1/2), which implies d(n)/(n^1/2) -> 0, which implies that ( d(n)^2)/n -> 0. Right?

Comment: I knew you could do it! You could write that up, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks alot Gerry!

Answer (score 0):

a) is false: "If  has ()=(^) for all >0, ()=()"

This is false because n=n^1, and 1 is not a member of  > 0

b) is true: "()=(^) implies (())^2=()"

This is true because ()=(^) implies

d(n)/n^ -> 0, which implies

d(n)/n^1/2 -> 0, which implies

d(n)^2/n -> 0, which implies

d(n)^2 = o(n)

Comment: In a), how do you reckon that $\epsilon=1$ doesn't satisfy $\epsilon>0$? Also, there is advice available through the help menu on how to format math on this website. Compare $d(n)/n^{1/2}\to0$ with your highly ambiguous d(n)/n^1/2 -> 0. And in the first sentence in b), you want $(d(n))^2$, not (d(n))2.

Comment: Oh , but isn’t epsilon a value between 0 and 1 not including 1? Thanks I’ll fix the formatting

Comment: "for all $\epsilon>0$" means for **ALL** $\epsilon>0$. Isn't $1$ bigger than zero? And, anyway, if $d(n)=o(n^{1/2})$, say, well, by now you should see that implies $d(n)=o(n)$.

Comment: I thought epsilon was a value between 0 and 1, not including either.

Comment: You were wrong.